# PHP: htmlentities/strip_tags

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, html-entities

I've been re-writing my website lately and added a Syntax highlighter so that I can post code snippets. Before, all I did was `htmlentities()` the string so that it would be safe and not break anything, but now that I have to use a `<pre>` to highlight code, `htmlentites()` effectively removes the syntax highlighting from the page. I've been trying to come up with a function that will just perform an `htmlentites()` on anything between two tags (`<entitiesparse>` `</entitiesparse>`) but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know of a function that I can either:

a) Set it to `htmlentities()` everything but specific tags (like `strip_tags()`)

OR

b) Only `htmlentities()` things in certain tags (As mentioned above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to apply `htmlentities()` to the raw content. So you can apply `htmlentities()` to the raw content (the article text) and then invoke a function to add syntax highlighting after that. So long as you check that your syntax highlighting code cannot introduce unexpected nasties, you don't need to call `htmlentities()` again.

And if you're saying that you use the `a` element to highlight code, I strongly suggest you use the `code` element instead, which is designed to provide markup for lines or blocks of programming code. The `a` element should only be used as an anchor for a hyperlink.

For instance, you could use

```
<code class="highlighted-code">/* line of code here /*</code>
```

Then you could use a cascading style sheet to provide background colour for any element of type `code` with class equal to "highlighted-code", for instance:

```
code.highlighted-code {background-color: yellow}
```